# Find feed rss for a given URL: Feedbag error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, rubygems

Please, note that I already found a way to find a feed rss from an URL and the question isn't about that, read the entire question before make precipitated conclusions.

I need find the RSS Feed from a given URL and I found a gem that do exactly that. This gem is called [Feedbag](https://github.com/damog/feedbag) and it's amazing, but I'm having some troubles to find rss feed for some popular websites like Gizmodo and Kotaku.

**If I try:**

```
Feedbag.find("http://g1.globo.com/index.html")
=> ["http://g1.globo.com/dynamo/rss2.xml"]
```

But, if I try some popular website like Kotaku:

```
Feedbag.find("http://www.kotaku.com.br/")
=> []
```

**I want to know:** why this gem cannot find the rss feed for sites like Kotaku and Gizmodo? Am I doing something wrong or the gem Feedbag is broken? What can I do to get a rss feed for all url's?

Thanks!

Comment: Taking a look at the gem's code, there is no option to go deep in level. It will only test links on the page you request to `find`. I've visited kotaku and I've seen no links to any kind of feed on the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I didn't found why this occurring. Since I don't going update this question / answer in the future, you can check the current status of my issue [on GitHub clicking here](https://github.com/damog/feedbag/issues/7).

I hope the developer has saw my issue, but until the moment I didn't get any tip.